# MS access update subform with another subform entire dataset

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to create a form that has 2 subforms. SF1 is a list of classes, just the names, in this subform I can add more classes.

now my issue is with SF2, this subform has the names of all the teachers, but I want the names of the teachers of the classes already displaying in SF1. example:

classes

```
math
english
history
```

teachers

```
herodoto
arquimedes
shakespeare
```

classTeacher

```
math-arquimedes
english-shakespeare
history-herodoto
english-arquimedes
math-herodoto
```

when loaded 1st time

SF1

```
english
```

SF2

```
shakespeare-english
arquimedes-english
```

2nd pass

SF1

```
english
math
```

SF2

```
math-arquimedes
english-shakespeare
english-arquimedes
math-herodoto
```

as far as I got was to display the first SF1 correctly, but SF2 displays all data regardless, so my question would be how to connect SF1 and get all the values there and have that as a filter in SF2????

**UPDATE**

ok here is the real issue I am facing. I am trying to create a ticket management system and I need to identify if the issue is already being worked on or not. for that I created a piece of code that analyzes the ticket detail and adds KEYWORDS to it, so far I was able to do that. my next step on this is to have a list of all the issues related to the keywords that are open and see if I can find a match. if I do, I just click on it and that ticket is now related to that open issue.

[image]

1 - the issue detail
2 - keywords list
3 - issue list

so again, my problem is to show all the issues related to the keywords list in 3 and showing the whole list is impractical as there are close to a hundred or more as time passes. some of the issues are just common and this can also be used as a knowledge base but that is the next step...

Comment: Please post the macro commands or module code of how SF2 is adjusted for SF1 criteria.

Comment: as of right now the data source for SF2 is a query with a 'select all from classTeacher', I was thinking of creating a dynamic query to append a 'where in' clause with the values of SF1, but I am new to this so I am still trying to figure what is the name of my SF1 to be referenced in the VBA :p

Comment: How is that the query if a filtered version shows in your section of *loaded first time*? If record source does not change it should always show all data.

Comment: Why not embed the second subform inside the first subform and have linked fields be the subject?

Comment: I didn't know i could embed a second time...but what I want is to see all the data at the same time and not look at it record by record. that is why if I add a class to the list I want to see all the professors at the same time as all the classes

Comment: You have 3 tables: Classes, Teachers, classTeacher? For data entry, conventional approach would be a main form for Classes, subform for classTeacher with a combobox to select teacher. Use subform container Master/Child Links properties to synchronize records.

Comment: Or is this what you want http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/Forms/Synchronize/LinkedSubforms.asp

Comment: @June7 close to your example but instead of just showing the detail for my one selection I want to get the details from all elements in the master. following your example, I would want to see: all the countries and all the carmakers and all the computer makers, if i add another 'master' list like phone makers i would like to add that list too. in my case, it would be all the english teachers and all the math teachers and all the hystory teachers

Comment: For what purpose? What you describe doesn't really make sense for a data entry process. Could have a form bound to classTeachers then use comboboxes or listboxes to list all items from Classes and Teachers for input into records.

Comment: i thought it would be easier to explain my dilema with an easier example then my real problem... what i am trying to do is actually a ticket managment system where i do a first pass through the issue details and get the keywords of the issue, now this key words are also related to the common 'issues', so some keywords will be related to many issues.

Comment: what I want to do is create a form where I can see the whole detail of the ticket: issue detail, servers related, channels, and so on. I want a subform that shows the list of keywords and because I will be adding keywords due to misspelling of the user I need to see all keywords. the second subform is a list of the possible issues that are already active and instead of creating a new ticket for dev I just assign the ticket to one of the opened dev tickets.